# WebApi: decide authentication scheme based on request header

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, owin-middleware

I am developing an ASP.NET Web API and want to allow different authentication schemes, the authentication method should be decided per request and by a request header.

**Example**
If the request contains the header "Bearer" I want to verify the token with Azure and determine authorization via application roles, if not I want to use Windows Authentication and determine authorization via Active Directory security groups.

**Problem** I have no problem getting each scheme to work in separate projects but am not able to figure out how to combine the two and select scheme based on the request headers.

1. Is it possible to decide authentication scheme when the request
   arrives, if so how?
2. Is it possible to perform Windows Authentication
   in the Owin pipeline instead of enabling it in IIS, if so how?

any pointers appreciated!

Comment: I wonder how would you manage Authorization and roles this way

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros I imagine that I would use a custom authorization filter, a class derived from AuthorizeAttribute.